# react + routing + security

Tags: security, reactjs, react-router, openam

I am building a web application with React and react-router and I would like to protect some routes of my React application with an existing external access management infrastructure ([OpenAM](https://forgerock.org/openam)).

I would like to protect the http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/#/user-profile url which means that only logged users can have access to this route.

I have some other routes which are public and any user can open them, for example http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/#/welcome.

The Access Management protects urls and if a user wants to open a protected url then a login form is shown by Access Management and after a successful login the original requested url will be displayed.

The problem here is that react-router adds the routing info after the '#' character and the above mentioned two different urls are same from the access manager point of view because they refer to the same web resource (/myapp). The different between these two urls appear after the '#' character.

I need to have real urls without '#' chars like this:

- http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/user-profile
- http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/welcome

Is there any way to use real url mappings with React?
Do you guys have any idea or workaround how to use real url routes with react?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
This is my code. The urls in the web browser look nice but I get a "about did not match any routes" error. Requested url: http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/about

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory} from 'react-router';
import {createHistory} from 'history';    

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory) ({
   basename: '/myapp/'
});

ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
         <IndexRoute component={Home} />
         <Route path="about" component={About} />
      </Route>
   </Router>
)
```

Comment: Well `react-router` supports using browser history like this, but you have to configure your server to serve the correct resources.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant wire-up of your routes? `react-router` supports `onEnter` props on its routes. You could write a function that gets invoked every time you hit it.

Comment: I added history={browserHistory} to my Router tag and I the # char gone. It looks nice. Now I have another issue. The root url is  http://web.example.com:8080/myapp and the welcome content is linked to http://web.example.com:8080/welcome instead of http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/welcome. Brrr...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `browserHistory`, as suggested in the comments, to get rid of the `#`-sign. If you want the root of your react-application to be `/myapp/` instead of `/` you can try:

```
import {Router, Route, useRouterHistory} from 'react-router';
import {createHistory} from 'history';    

const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({basename: '/myapp/'});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    ...
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now the url what I can see in the browser looks nice. When i click on the home Link then web.example.com:8080/myapp appears. When I click on the 'About' link then I can see  web.example.com:8080/myapp/about in the browser. But something wrong with the mapping because an "/about did not match any routes" error appears on the browser's console. I have added my current routing code to the original post. What is wrong with my mapping? Thx.

Comment: @zappee, hmm weird. Try putting the route as `<Route path="/about" component={About} />` instead. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not close this topic. The routing logic works, I can see the proper content if I click on the Link and the the url looks so pretty. But I need to go back to the original question :( I think that the url what appears in the browser is just a fake url. When I want to reload it ( http://web.example.com:8080/myapp/about) then I get a HTTP 404. So react-router just overwrite the browser's url as a "string".

Comment: And the browser does NOT do anything with this new, modified url and browser does NOT load this fake url when I click on the link. JavaScript does some magic at the background. And because this is just a fake url and browser does not send any request when I click on the link my URL based security does not work. User can have access to any protected url :((( Do you know any workaround to solve my original question?

Comment: `react-router` is meant not to make any requests to the server. Those are indeed "fake" urls. You need to configure your application appropriately. For example, if you are requesting `myapp/about`, the server must **always** handle as if you requested `myapp/`. This really depends on how your backend works, but here's a [good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdUyEou0LHg) to get your started.

Comment: Thx for the video!!! That was very useful. Only one solution come up off the top of me head. I need to use two real html files. One for the public routes and contents and another for the public + protected contents together. And if user click on a protected link then react-router needs to make somehow a redirect to the /myapp/private.html file. It is seems as a stupid solution but i have no another idea at the moment :(( Can I put two webpack config file in the same folder to create two different boundle.js files? For example public-boundle.js and protected-boundle.js.

Comment: Getting a bit too complicated without knowing your project too well. You might be able to but not sure if that's a good approach.

Comment: Or maybe I need to use another framework on the UI side, like angular? I really do not know.

Comment: Keep searching friend. Perhaps post a new question and add more details. It's hard (for me at least) to understand 100% how your whole app looks like and what the problem is. Good luck.

Comment: 1st step towards the solution: add this to the web.xm file: <error-page><error-code>404</error-code><location>/index.html</location></error-page> With this trick the fake urls become reals on Apache-Tomcat :)

Comment: final step: use <a href="myapp/about">about</a> instead of <Link to='about'>about</Link> That way the browser will send a request so Access Management can catch the request and check the login status of the user. That is it :)